Change delegate if listelement is true
I am trying to use Pathview to show a carousel, when an element in my model has a certain field set as true, I would like to display an image next to the item in the carousel.
I have tried to mock up some code that shows what I am trying to do, where the star.jpg will show if the item at currentIndex has favorite=true.
property var currentItem: ListModel.get(mypathView.currentIndex)

 ListModel {
        id:sampleModel
         ListElement {
             name: "first"
             favorite: false
             
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "second"
             favorite: true
        }
         ListElement {
             name: "third"
             favorite: false
        }

         ListElement {
             name: "fourth"
             favorite: false
         }
     }


Component {
    id: myDelegate

    Item {
        width: vpx(300)
        height: vpx(150)
        scale: PathView.iconScale
        opacity: PathView.iconOpacity
        z: PathView.iconOrder

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "transparent"
            
        
        Image {
            id:listicon
            
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "square.jpg"
        }
        }

       Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "transparent"
            visible: currentItem.favorite==true
            
        
        Image {
            id:favicon
            
            anchors.left: listicon
            source: "star.jpg"
        }
        }
}
}

PathView {
        id: mypathView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        pathItemCount: 7
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5                         
        preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5                           
        highlightRangeMode: PathView.StrictlyEnforceRange   
        
        model: sampleModel
        delegate: myDelegate
        

        path: Path {
            startX: 0; startY: 0
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 0.2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 10.2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOrder"; value: 0 }
            PathLine {x: mypathView.width / 2; y: mypathView.height/2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 1.5 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 1 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOrder"; value: 8 }
            PathLine {x: 0; y: mypathView.height}
            }


This looks like a typo. You're using visible: currentItem.favorite=true. You need to use == or === instead of = because you're comparing values, not assigning them.

Ah sorry, that is a typo. I've corrected it now, it still does not work though

It seems that you have an error when you try to access the model item property favorite from the delegate.
I remember you that a delegate has access to all model properties. Don't make sense to store the current PathView item in a separate variable (it's also bad to call it without its root ID and PathView already has the property currentItem).
Call favorite directly from your delegate (the syntax should change given the model definition). You can ensure the result by forcing the model property as required. Below a working example of your delegate
Component {
    id: myDelegate

    Item {
        required property var model

        width: 300
        height: 150
        scale: PathView.iconScale
        opacity: PathView.iconOpacity
        z: PathView.iconOrder

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "indianred"
        }

        Rectangle {
            visible: model.favorite === true
            width: 15
            height: 15
            anchors {
                right: parent.right
                bottom: parent.bottom
                margins: 5
            }

            color: "gold"
        }
    }
}


Thank you! This is working, although my issue is now that the image displays on all items in the carousel when the model.favorite=true.

I don't understand why it's an issue, it was your request: > when an element in my model has a certain field set as true, I would like to display an image next to the item in the carousel

I'd like to display the image next to only that item, not all items in the carousel

My suggestion outputs what you expect. You can find a working example here: https://gist.github.com/lorenzoaldrighetti/e3c7b3e86123c0b4ea04726288d1db9f with an image as a comment with the demonstration

You are 100% right! It's working!!! Thank you so much!!!
